# Reading json objects separated by new line

Tags: java, json

I am trying to write a test case where I want to stream json objects from a json file separated by new line into Java.

I want to stream one event object in Java and serialize it.

The json file is of the form:

> {"event":[{"D49-64":0,"Bezeichnung":"A 41","D33-48":0}]}
>
> {"event":[{"D49-64":1,"Bezeichnung":"A 41","D33-48":0}]}

Any suggestions to stream the objects in Java will be beneficial.

Comment: Your json is broken

Comment: I found this blog quite useful: [Line-delimited JSON with Jackson](https://cowtowncoder.medium.com/line-delimited-json-with-jackson-69c9e4cb6c00).

Answer (score 2):

The blob that you have posted is not a valid JSONObject, but two individual objects.

To *stream* this, you would end up with something like the following:

```
String pathToFile = "/path/to/something.txt";

BufferedReader someReader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( pathToFile ));

String someData;
while (( someData = someReader.readLine() ) != null ) {

    JSONObject o = new JSONObject( someData );

    doSomethingWith( o );
}
```

The library I generally use for JSON manipulation is [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json)

Answer (score 0):

I was solving the same problem: reading data from file which just has sequence of json objects in it. I am using [com.fasterxml.jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) library for json manipulation. While it does not have direct methods for exactly this, the solution is  still quite simple:

```
  // InputStream in - input stream with your data
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  JsonParser parser = mapper.getFactory().createParser(in);
  ObjectNode nextObject;
  do {
    nextObject = mapper.readTree(parser); // returns null when end of stream is reached
    // process your object here
  } while(nextObject != null);
```